# C# GridView, Combobox Date Range

Tags: c#, date, gridview, range

I have problem on date range query in C# WinForms. If i select 03/26/2015 as start date and 03/27/2015 as end date on the two combo boxes, it shows all the data for 03/27/2015 only and not the data from 03/26/2015 to 03/27/2015.

Here is the code:

```
                    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                    dateTimePicker.Value = date;
                    dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";

                    DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;
                    dateTimePicker2.Value = date2;
                    dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    SQL

    patients.entry_datetime >= @startDate and patients.entry_datetime <= @endDate

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", dateTimePicker.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", dateTimePicker2.Value);
```

Comment: You are assigning DateTime.Now for both date fields.

Comment: i have tried and i get same results


`code`
     dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
     dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";

     dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
     dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";`code`

Comment: So you need Date to be passed to SQL not Time?

Comment: Convert the date into the datetime and use datetime parameter in sql also. It will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the `DateTime` formatted with `CustomFormat` the value passed from `dateTimePicker.Value` will be in `DateTime` format not `Date` format. So you need to convert `DateTime` in SQL query will solve your issue. (Assuming you have stored the `patients.entry_datetime` as `DateTime` in your SQL server.

So try the SQL query like this,

```
patients.entry_datetime >= CAST(@startDate AS DATE) 
AND patients.entry_datetime <= CAST(@endDate AS DATE)
```

Comment: @KevinRodriguez The above code worked for me. Please post the error what you have got.

Comment: I have checked my database the datetime column doesnt have time, this maybe the issue?

Comment: No, even the Date type also the CONVERT supports in SQL. What is your RDBMS? SQL Server or MySql?

Comment: this is the error Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR, patients.entry_datetime, 101) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR, '2015-03-26 14:06:44 ' at line 1

Comment: Then try like this,   `patients.entry_datetime >=  CAST(@startDate AS DATE) 
AND patients.entry_datetime  <= CAST(@endDate AS DATE)`

Comment: @KevinRodriguez In your code, you are formatting Date with custom format not time. So obviously when you try to pass the value to Sql, it passes the Date with Time also. In Sql the 'Where' condition checks with Time also. So it not gives you exact result. For the conversion error, I have assumed it is MS SQL server so you have received conversion error.